# Nonparametric ANOVA for simulated data

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric

I have some simulated data and I want to test whether "group" has an effect. The data are from a Weibull distribution. because the data are simulated, I can determine sample size, however this also leads to problems with significance tests.

I am wanting to perform a simulation based (resampling/bootstrap) for multiple (>2) groups, but just not sure how to do it.

Here is some example code

```
n = 1000
a = rweibull(n,scale = 98, shape = .74)
b = rweibull(n,scale = 111, shape = .74)
c = rweibull(n,scale = 71, shape = .98)

a = data.frame(grp = as.factor("a"),value = a)
b = data.frame(grp = as.factor("b"),value = b)
c = data.frame(grp = as.factor("c"),value = c)

df = rbind(a,b,c)

kruskal.test(value ~ grp,data = df)
```

With n = 1000, test is significant. Not so at n = 100.
I have performed testing of mean differences using resampling before, but not sure how to extend to more than two groups.